# CSRF protection possible with pure static site?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, csrf

I have a standalone single page React app which communicates with a separate API app for data. The app is entirely static (just HTML, JS, CSS, and images) except for a tiny Express server for CSRF protection support. The app contains forms the user fills out and submits (submission happens via HTTP request).

I’d really love to move away from direct reliance on a cloud server and move to hosting purely with S3 + Cloudfront. This is totally doable as all assets are static, and I can invalidate index.html on deploy. My only hang up is CSRF protection.

Currently I rely on express-session backend by Redis along with a session cookie. The CSRF token is injected into a server-side rendered index route which bootstraps the client side React app.

Is there a safe (as safe as it is now), feasible way to have a pure static site with CSRF support? The app will have full access to the separate API service.

Comment: What are you looking to protect from request forgery on a static site?

Comment: Forms submitted via HTTP request.

Comment: Yes okay but forms that do what exactly? You have some backend logic in there, use it.

Comment: The forms are used to submit data to the backend via POST which expects a CSRF token provided by the client. This CSRF token is then matched against the expected token. Traditionally, CSRF tokens are injected into HTML on server-side render. My question is whether there is a secure alternative to injecting tokens via server-side render as there will no longer be any server-side rendering occurring.